# Android - How to slow down battery Drain

Tags: android, game-engine, battery

I am developing a game for Android. It uses a surface view and uses Bitmaps to draw objects each frame, redrawing on the Bitmap objects only when required.
Using the app I noticed that the battery is draining.
I would like to know if there is a library to understand which part I am consuming a lot of battery in or a way to apply the battery safety function in my surface view.
Each bitmap in the game is recycled every time it is instantiated. So apart from this little trick I don't know how to optimize my code.
Can anyone suggest me what I can do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact solution to minimize battery usage - it depends on your code, and it's all about minimizing CPU & Network usage. Basically you already have powerful Profiler in your Android Studio. It shows CPU, RAM, network & battery usage on dashboards and you can find most heavy part of your code using it. More you optimize your code, more effectively app will use battery.

[image]

[image]

[image]